# Is there a way to avoid duplicate user creation on this case?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm creating a Flask App to analyze some behavior in my company. And the intranet website sends me some webhook to tell me when someone logs in somewhere.

The problem is that sometimes the intranet send me 2 times the same webhook and my decorator first_or_create_user looks to be triggered at the same time so it creates two times the user if they didn't exist.

So I receive webhooks with some information:

```
{
  'id': 9349813, 
  'begin_at': '2019-08-20 05:34:53 UTC', 
  'end_at': None, 
  'host': '<ip>', 
  'user': {
    'id': 62812, 
    'login': '<login>'
  }
}
```

my route is written like that:

```
@intrahook.route('', methods=["POST"])
@check_params
@first_or_create_user
def index(user):
    return _hook_handler(request.headers.get("X-Model"), request.headers.get("X-Event"), request.json)
```

and my decorator:

```
def first_or_create_user(f):
    wraps(f)
    def get_user(*args, **kwargs):
        data = request.json
        user = User.query.filter_by(
            intra_id=data['user']['id']
        ).first()

        if user is None:
            intra_user = ic.get(f"users/{data['user']['id']}").json()

            user = User(
                    intra_id=data['user']['id'],
                    login=data['user']['login'],
                    first_name=intra_user['first_name'],
                    last_name=intra_user['last_name'],
                    pool_year=intra_user['pool_year'],
                    pool_month=intra_user['pool_month']
                )

            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()

            logger.info(f"user_creation: {data['user']['login']}")

        return f(user, *args, **kwargs)
    return get_user
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to lock/avoid the first_or_create_user to be triggered at the same time.

I know that the intra shouldn't send the same call at the same time but I'm not a maintainer of the intranet website and sadly, I can't improve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Isnt `User`s column `intra_id` unique? If it was at least you wouldn't end up with two rows, but an error instead.

Comment: yep, make `intra_id` unique in your table and it will complain out loud, but not duplicate data ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I did add unique=True to the intra_id column and login.

And finally found how to "fix" this issue.

Actually, the intra api take too much time to answer me for this call:

```
intra_user = ic.get(f"users/{data['user']['id']}").json()
```

So I just added another check before saving in db.

Here is the final code:

```
def first_or_create_user(f):
    wraps(f)
    def get_user(*args, **kwargs):
        data = request.json
        user = User.query.filter_by(
            intra_id=data['user']['id']
        ).first()

        if user is None:
            intra_user = ic.get(f"users/{data['user']['id']}").json()

            user = User(
                    intra_id=data['user']['id'],
                    login=data['user']['login'],
                    first_name=intra_user['first_name'],
                    last_name=intra_user['last_name'],
                    pool_year=intra_user['pool_year'],
                    pool_month=intra_user['pool_month']
                )

            u = User.query.filter_by(intra_id=data['user']['id']).first()
            if u is None:
                db.session.add(user)
                db.session.commit()
                logger.info(f"user_creation: {data['user']['login']}")
            else:
                return f(u, *args, **kwargs)
        return f(user, *args, **kwargs)
    return get_user
```

Thank you for your help.